# Why does <Ctrl-E> behave differently in the insert mode opened with r or i?

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem understanding `<Ctrl-E>` (and `<Ctrl-Y>` for that reason too) usage in the insert mode.

Why after `3r<Ctrl-E>` this source text:

```
123 456 789
qwe rty uio
```

Turns into:

```
qwe 456 789
qwe rty uio
```

But `3i<Ctrl-E><Esc>` turns that into:

```
qqq123 456 789
qwe rty uio
```

instead of (what I would be expecting):

```
qwe123 456 789
qwe rty uio
```

Why does the `<Ctrl-E>` update every repeat in the first case and not in the second? (In all examples, cursor starts at the start of the file).

Comment: Where is your cursor starting in these examples?

Comment: @FDinoff clarified (also removed unused first lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help for `r`

```
If {char} is CTRL-E or CTRL-Y the character from the
line below or above is used, just like with i_CTRL-E
and i_CTRL-Y.  This also works with a count, thus
10r<C-E> copies 10 characters from the line below.
```

So CTRL-E is run for every character that is being replaced. On the other hand the help for `i` says

```
Insert text before the cursor [count] times.
```

So when you hit `3i<c-e><esc>` it says start insert mode, insert the character under cursor. In this case you inserted `q`. So vim goes and inserts `q` 3 times. Vim does not remember that you used `<c-e>`.

---

Also since you seem to be misunderstanding something from your title. `r` open replace mode, not insert mode.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I was going through the manual, trying everything, and just gone through that place, but it's very far from being as clear as your explanation.